# Change tracking after reboot

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

We have 2 SQL Server servers (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 12.0.6433.1 Enterprise Edition and Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Standard) that have been logging change tracking procedure failed with too many arguments. All databases do not have change tracking enabled. We tried enabling change tracking on the database and then disabling change tracking. This did not work.

> Procedure or function sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand has too many arguments specified.

received after reboot.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: `sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand` is undocumented and unsupported, and takes one optional parameter `@numrows bigint`. Whatever process you have that uses it probably needs fixing. Check SQL Server Agent jobs, Scheduled Tasks, and Cronjobs.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 12.0.6433.1 Enterprise Edition and Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Standard and both do not have change tracking enabled